# Node-red container can't be installed

Tags: docker, ubuntu, node-red, permission-denied

I tried for so many hours now and tried so many things that I have to ask now.
On my docker I can't get nodered to run on it. I get permissions error for the shared volume all the time. My other container for "fhem" does run with the same folder permissions. So i don't get why its a problem for nodered.

Currently I'm using ubuntu on the latest version.

I want to store the /data folder from the nodered instance in /opt/docker-nodered but this doesn't work.

I tried to install it with the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 1880:1880 -v /opt/docker-nodered/:/data --name nodered nodered/node-red-docker
```

The permissions here are the following:

```
stefmde@homeautomation:/opt$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 stefmde stefmde 4096 Sep 24 09:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root    4096 Sep 21 18:56 ../
drwxr-xr-x 10 stefmde stefmde 4096 Sep 22 12:48 docker-fhem/
drwxr-xr-x  2 stefmde stefmde 4096 Sep 24 14:01 docker-nodered/
```

I changed them with the following to try to get it running:

```
chown -R stefmde:stefmde /opt/docker-nored
```

But no mather what I try, I always get the same error:

```
stefmde@homeautomation:/opt/docker-nodered$ sudo docker run -it -p 1880:1880 -v /opt/docker-nodered/:/data --name nod ered nodered/node-red-docker

> node-red-docker@1.0.0 start /usr/src/node-red
> node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js -v $FLOWS "--userDir" "/data"

fs.js:642
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/data/settings.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:642:18)
    at copyFileFallback (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:93:18)
    at copyFile (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:85:10)
    at onFile (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:58:12)
    at getStats (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:51:39)
    at startCopy (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:41:10)
    at Object.copySync (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:36:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/red.js:104:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start" "--" "--userDir" "/data"
npm ERR! node v6.14.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-red-docker@1.0.0 start: `node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js -v $FLOWS "--userDir" "/data"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-red-docker@1.0.0 start script 'node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js -v $FLOWS  "--userDir" "/data"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-red-docker package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js -v $FLOWS "--userDir" "/data"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-red-docker
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-red-docker
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/node-red/npm-debug.log
```

The npm.debug.log-file doesn't exist

I tried different permission sets, I checked the UUID which is 1000 of my user, I tried to run "npm install" manually, checked different bug tickets on github, tried the "--User"-Flag which isn't working, running the docker command with and without "sudo" and so on.

Please can someone try to help me or tell me what i did wrong?
I hope you could :)

Answer (score 5):

The node-red docker container runs as the user `node-red`, a lot of other docker containers run the application as the default user, which happens to be root.

At the moment your `docker-nodered` directory is only writable by the user `stefmde` and `root` (because root can write to anywhere)

The quick solution is to make the `docker-nodered` writable by anybody (`chmod o+w docker-nodered`) this should work.

The longer solution will be to work out what the UID of the `node-red` user is, add a group to the host OS that has a member with the same UID as `node-red` and make the directory owned by that group and then make it group writable (`chmod g+w docker-nodered`)

EDIT: The default uid:gid for the node-red user is 1000:1000

Comment: Hi, thanks for your hint. But there is no "nodered" user in the host systems passwd-file. Do I have to create it? Does the user need to have a special UUID? But with the 'short'-hint it worked. Now it looks like its installing correctly.

Comment: There won't be a local user called `node-red` because it only exists in the container. If you look in the folder now you should see files prefer by the user, they will just have a number not a name, that will be the UID. You will be able to use this to create a local user to add to a suitable group

Comment: I think you need to use the _--user_ option when running the command.  See e.g.  https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15

Answer (score 1):

By far, the easiest method is to change ownership of the Node-RED data folder to user 1000 and group 1000, as this is hard-coded in the Node-RED docker container:

```
sudo chown 1000:1000 name-of-node-red-data-folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I've workaround that worked for me using docker-compose. I've created the file `docker-compose-node-red.yml` with the following content:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  node-red:
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    volumes:
      - "/path/to/a-nodered-project:/data"
```

Then, I run

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-node-red.yml up
```

In the folder `/path/to/a-nodered-project` I have a flows.json file and others. Everything is accessible from the node-red container perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by just creating the local folders BEFORE starting docker/compose, so it does not create them as root user.